# Are there type inference optimizations on V8?

Tags: javascript, v8

Well, another optimization question. I'd like to know whether V8 *does* type inference on variables and then *optimize* accesses based on that variable.

Type inference would be something like this:

```
let input = "keyboard";
//  ^^^^^ input is String because "keyboard" is String
```

Are there situations on that V8 may not infer a type and accidentaly not optimize it, e.g., because the type of certain expression can only be got at run time?

**Putting `zxc` to local `s`**

```
let s = ''; // let s : String

s = zxc; // What is zxc?
```

**Alternative**

```
let s = '';

s = zxc + '';
```

Comment: maybe this contains  what you are looking for?https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/

Comment: @Shyam Almost...

Comment: javascript is all about optimizing stuff for quick access...

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, but what if the compiler doesn't optimize it at all?

Comment: javascript is a dynamic language where c++ is static. there's different considerations that have to be made.

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you check again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.

For example, from 2012 year V8 tags 32bit numbers so every calculation with 'em a lot faster. proof https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/#toc-topic-numbers

Crankshaft introduces hybrid type inference everywhere to speed up every field access of unchanged type.

Current Ignition does more and better and of course builds native code paths using knowledge of field types.

And it has its own price of deoptimization when somebody writes value of unpredicted type to known field.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much relevant about type tagging yet. :/

Answer (score 0):

(V8 developer here.) The short answer is "yes and no". The long answer is complicated.

There is no direct "type inference for variables" as in the `let s = '';` example -- precisely because the next assignment could be `s = 1`.

That said, one of the basic principles how modern JavaScript engines (V8 and others) generate optimized code is by observing which types have been seen at a particular point in the program. For example, when you have `... = s + t`, and so far `s` and `t` have always been strings, then optimized code will contain a sequence roughly like:

```
check if the value in s is a string, otherwise bail out;
check if the value in s is a string, otherwise bail out;
perform a string concatenation of the two values;
```

where "bail out" means that the optimized code for the entire function is thrown away, and execution continues with unoptimized code (or bytecode) which makes no baked-in assumptions about types. New optimized code may or may not be generated later, based on updated information about types. This approach is not what's usually called "type inference" though.

Direct "type inference" in JavaScript is only possible in very limited circumstances. For example, the result of a bitwise operation (like `|`, `&`, 
`~`) is always a 32-bit integer; the result of unary plus (i.e. `+foo`) is always a number; the result of adding a string to anything else is always a string. Optimizing compilers typically apply such rules to generate more efficient code.